# Grails Local Plugin Render

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm trying to access methods from controllers in a local plugin. I included the plugin like so:

```
grails.plugin.location.'helloworld' = "../helloworld"
```

I want to invoke the hello() method and pass in some params to it. I tried the following from the index page of my app:

```
<g:include plugin="helloworld" action="index" controller="hello" model="['name':'John Doe']"></g:include>
```

Here is the controller method in the plugin:

```
package helloworld

class HelloController {

    def index() {
        println "working"
    }
}
```

I'm trying to keep it simple and get it to work before I worry about rendering views and processing parameters. I'm sure my approach is not the right way, I just need someone to point me in the right direction please.

Comment: So, what is your question? What does your include produce? Is it what you expected or not?

Comment: I'd expect to see "working" in the console log and thats about it. Maybe you need to `render` some output?

Comment: @nickdos, you're right, just as you expected. I don't know how I overlooked something as simple as not pointing to the right project. I had an old helloworld sample app that was in my working directory. The plugin was in the sub-directory containing the other test project and I was pointing to the wrong one. It is printing to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
package helloworld

class HelloController {

    def index() {
        render "working"
    }
}
```